# How to change a HTML-element to the selection of a File-Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, dialog

I am currently working on a python program that uses a html/css interface which is connected through eel. It requires the user to load a file to analyze. In order to show the user on the User interface which file was selected, I want to show the name of the file (or the path) after the selection process is done.

Since I am new to this, I found a simple filedialog on the internet (probably somewhere here on Stackoverflow) that uses JQuery to select the path to a file. The selection works fine and my program can work with that information if the file that is being selected is located in the same folder as the html file, as this circumvents fakepath errors and I do not know a way around it.

I want to display the selected path underneath the button once it has been selected. However, in the current configuration it displays [object object] right after clicking the "Browserino" button and not the selected path or (ideally) the selected filename.

The HTML document contains:

```
<div class="col">
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clicked();">Browserino</button>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
  <small id="pathway" class="form-text text-muted">invisible</small>
</div>
```

And the main.js has this function to work with:

```
function clicked(){
    var path = String($('#file-input').trigger('click'));
    document.getElementById('pathway').innerHTML = path;
    document.getElementById('pathway').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

I have also tried the follwing in the main.js, but it does not do the trick for me:

```
function clicked(){
    String($('#file-input').trigger('click'));
    var file_input = document.getElementById('file-input').value;
    var filepath = file_input.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    document.getElementById('pathway').innerHTML = filepath;
}
```

Thanks for all the comments before, I hope this edit helps clarify the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: You can't, the exact path is obfuscated, you can only get "fake path". This is a security feature, without a work-around.

Comment: To add to the above, you're seeing `[Object object]` in the output because `path` holds a jQuery object, not a string.

Comment: Wow. Quick response. Thank you. I actually use a workaround where the .html is stored in the same file-location as the file I want to select. Therefore, it would be fine to just display the filename of the selected file after the file has been selected. However, within the clicked function (shown above) I do not get it to work and all it displays is [object object] right after opening the file-dialog and not when a file as actually been selected. Any ideas how I can modify the function to do what I want?

Comment: Wait! "_the .html is stored in the same file-location as the file I want to select_". Is this a locally hosted page? In that case you can read the path from `location` object.

Comment: I have taken your comments and updated the question accordingly to clarify the problem. Thank you for the prompt responses!